# Can I search by application type/usage/category instead of application name in Unity Application lens?

Tags: unity

Most of the times, application search works great in application lens. Search for an application name and you will get it. But say if I forgot the application name but only remember its use - say I forgot the name "AvideMux" but I remember its an video editor, How do I search for it - search for "video editor" ? But when I search, its not returning avidemux as search result.

So my question is how do I let unity know that avidemux is a video editor and when I search for video editor , it should give me avidemux. Should I have to add any metadata to its .desktop file? How do I solve the same more generically - Search not just by application name but by application type and application usage as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that when you search in the lens, your term will be used to search for an application or an application with the keyword in the comment. So, there's a way to change that.

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
ls
```

When you find the launcher of the application you want, run:

```
sudo gedit AvideMux.desktop
```

(Using AvideMux as an example)

In the window, find the line "Comment" and add the words "video editor", for example. This should make it so that your search should bring up your application of choice.

Comment: Though answer is not generic, it still solves the purpose. Thanks.